# file_fdw Access csv file on a remote server

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, foreign-data-wrapper

Creating a foreign table like this:

```
CREATE FOREIGN TABLE xxxx
(... )
SERVER file
OPTIONS (filename '/data/data.csv', format 'csv', delimiter ';');
```

In the filename Option, Is it possible to specify a csv file that is on a remote server or the file as to be on the DB server? Both DB and Application server are Centos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not specify remote file for file_fdw.

> filename
>
> ```
>         Specifies the file to be read. Required. Must be an absolute path name.
> ```

The only one way access to remote file without copying - mount fs with it (nfs, samba, etc).

Comment: can you please elaborate on this? I have files on another server and I want to be able to access to them from remote server. So having absolute paths, means that input files should be on the same server as postgreSQL server?(I am writing fdw for Hdf5 files with multicorn)